# Range of rational functions in artificially defined domains

Tags: calculus, functions

Consider a rational function (Quadratic/Quadratic form in particular) for which the domain has been artificially defined.In normal cases,when the domain is only a subject to standard restrictions according to the definition of functions we assume the rational function equal to y and form a quadratic in x and then put the discriminant greater than or equal to 0.But how to proceed in such cases?(besides maxima and minima)

Comment: What are the “standard restrictions”? I think an example of what you’re thinking of would make answering easier.

Comment: If i were to find the range of x/x^2+2=y, i would have proceeded as i explained above. But what if the question restricts the domain of x to say [1,infinity). Is there any other method besides maxima minima for this? As far as i can see i will express x in terms of y and the  put the required constraint but then x in terms of y yields two values with a and that too under a square root,how to solve such a messy inequality?

Comment: If, as in your case, the domain is an interval, the local maxima and minima are to be found at endpoints and places where the derivative is zero. Only finitely many points for you to evaluate your function at. I do hope you’ve sketched the graph.